# Removing specific html column on excel export - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export-to-excel

I am exporting an html table to excel using IE9, and i want to avoid specific column on export. Currently using a javascript function.

I have totally 16 columns where i want to avoid 14th column on export. Can anyone help? Thanks for your time!

My code :

```
function ExcelReport() {
        var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr border='1px'>";
        var tabcol = "<td>";
        var j = 0;
        var i = 0;
        tab = document.getElementById('myTable'); 
        var col = tab.rows[1].cells.length;

        //row[0] is table header
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[0].innerHTML + "</td></tr>";

        for (j = 1; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
            for(i = 0 ;i< col;i++){
                tabcol = tabcol + tab.rows[j].cells[i].innerHTML + "</td>";
            }
            tab_text = tab_text + tabcol + "</tr>";
        }

        tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer
        {
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
            txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus();
            sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true,"Report.xls");
        } 

        return (sa);
    }
```

This code doesn't work. What should be done to remove the 14th column from the table. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just be a case of skipping the 14th column when importing the data?

```
if(i!=14) {

    }
```